# Nativescript app rejected - binary crashed on launch -

Tags: binary, crash, nativescript

I have NativeScript simple app which is based on Vuejs template. The app is super simple and loading HTML simple game to WebView of only one component Homve.vue.

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
      <WebView 
        :src="gameURL"
        bounces="false"
        ref="myWebView"
        @loaded="onWeViewLoaded" 
      />
    </Page>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        computed: {
            message() {
                return "Hello from Opart 2019";
            }
        },
        data() {
          return {
            gameURL: "~/assets/www/index.html"
          }
        },
        created() {
          //console.log('Home - created')
        },
        mounted() {
          //console.log('Home - mounted')
        },
        methods: {
          onWeViewLoaded() {
            //console.log('onWeViewLoaded')
            //this.$refs.myWebView.setAttribute('scrollView.bounces','false');
            //console.dir(this.$refs.myWebView.src)
          }
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

  .page {

  }

</style>
```

This app is super simple and never crashed on start testing locally on iPhone 7Plus, iPad Mini 2 with the latest iOS 12.4 but has been rejected on App Store Connect.

1.1 Binary Rejected - We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Crash logs:
https://github.com/sylwesterdigital/appstore-nativescript-crashes

Below snippet from one of crashlogs:

```
{"app_name":"flaynative","timestamp":"2019-08-18 19:39:21.92 -0700","app_version":"1.1.1","slice_uuid":"3405f8e2-670c-3bd9-9c98-012dfbc24c9f","adam_id":1476202200,"build_version":"1.1.1","bundleID":"com.flaboy.oldflay","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.4 (16G77)","incident_id":"5C7CF351-D0F6-45E2-878C-C3EB3D620C97","name":"flaynative"}
Incident Identifier: 5C7CF351-D0F6-45E2-878C-C3EB3D620C97
CrashReporter Key:   4966d39ab305f825353b3c62041a83ff7279f465
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             flaynative [726]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/64AB551F-ECAA-4CF4-AF2C-9998EC6D4421/flaynative.app/flaynative
Identifier:          com.flaboy.oldflay
Version:             1.1.1 (1.1.1)
AppStoreTools:       10G3
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.flaboy.oldflay [679]


Date/Time:           2019-08-18 19:39:21.8059 -0700
Launch Time:         2019-08-18 19:39:20.0711 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.4 (16G77)
Baseband Version:    7.80.04
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1828a598c 0x181a7e9f8 0x100b8248c 0x100bc2028 0x100497420 0x1822f58e0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001824420dc 0x18241f000 + 143580
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001824bb094 0x1824b9000 + 8340
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018239aea8 0x182340000 + 372392
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181a67788 0x181a66000 + 6024
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181a67934 0x181a66000 + 6452
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181a7ee00 0x181a79000 + 24064
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181a73838 0x181a66000 + 55352
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181a731a8 0x181a66000 + 53672
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181a73168 0x181a66000 + 53608
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181a7eb3c 0x181a79000 + 23356
10  NativeScript                    0x0000000100b8248c 0x100b3c000 + 287884
11  NativeScript                    0x0000000100bc2028 0x100b3c000 + 548904
12  flaynative                      0x0000000100497420 0x100490000 + 29728
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001822f58e0 0x1822f4000 + 6368
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the crash on your end?

Comment: When you are testing the app locally (on a real device), make sure you use the `--release` flag when running the app.

Comment: The app starts without any problems on my iPhone7S, iPad Mini2. I have published that app and very similar app via ```tns publish ios --appleApplicationSpecificPassword``` - this way I have produced ```/app/appname/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphoneos/appname.xcarchive``` and relevant ```appname.ipa```

Comment: My bad. Finally i have figured out that in ```build.xcconfig``` I need to manually define ```CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY``` and ```DEVELOPMENT_TEAM``` - then ```$ tns build ios --release``` does the job properly.